# quiz webpage checked all answers

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<html>

<head>
</head> 

// how to make them checked all question ??
<form method="post" action="data.php">
<table>
<tr>
                <td><label> I am a high achiever. </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 11 -->
<td>question2</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>question3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
                <td><label> question4 </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr><!-- 14 -->
<tr>
                <td><label> I am strong willed. </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="10"> 10 </td>

            </tr><!-- 15 -->
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Score my test"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

i wanted to make sure the user clicked all question , how i going to do that ? i wanted they answers all question , if they didt answers all and click submit button it wont work.do i some how using php or JavaScript to do this ?

Comment: use php for security aspect!, use optional javascript to disable the submit if not all radios are checked ...

Comment: YOU CAN USE .Checked property in js

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Form Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088538/javascript-form-validation)

Comment: is there a php Form Validation ???

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure you are consequent with your input fields. E.g. the first input field of question 2 have the name `I1` while the next have the name `Iquestion[1]`. Make sure they have all the same structure, you would get somethink like this:

```
<form method="post" action="data.php" id="answerForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label> I am a high achiever. </label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr><!-- 11 -->
        <td>question2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>question3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> question4 </label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr><!-- 14 -->
        <tr>
            <td><label> I am strong willed. </label></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="1"> 1 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="2"> 2 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="3"> 3 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="4"> 4 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="5"> 5 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="6"> 6 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="7"> 7 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="8"> 8 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="9"> 9 </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr><!-- 15 -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Score my test"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Also note that i added an `id` to the form. We need to use this for catching the `submit` event. For the event-handling you can use AJAX. Here you can check how many different radio inputs there are and how many are submitted. With this knowlegde it's possible to compare these values and based on the result you can go through with submission or show an `alert` (or any other kind of message you want). To catch the `submit` event and determine the follow-up action you can use something like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).on('submit', '#answerForm',function(e)
    {       
        var data                = $(this).serializeArray();
        var questions           = new Array();
        var questionsCounter    = 0;

        $.each($('input[type="radio"]'), function()
        {
            if(questions.indexOf($(this).attr('name')) == -1)
            {
                questions.push($(this).attr('name'));
                questionsCounter++;
            }           
        });

        if(questionsCounter != data.length)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You did not answer all questions");
        }       

    });

</script>
```

Note that this is client-side and isn't save, because client-side scripts can be manipulated. You should use this only for usable purpose and also create a check in your PHP script if all answers are filled.

Comment: do it really need to Jquery to do this ? can it be pure php ? well i just wanted to noticeable them , but your idea is cool i learned much.thank you

Comment: how to i make link to other site when is filled ? i filled all and it still say you did not answer all question.

Comment: Really? That's odd. Are you sure your html table is correct? You did use the same `name` attributes all time? What if you try the form in my answer, does that work?

Comment: And yes, ofcourse you could do this in PHP to, you should make a check in PHP to if they are all filled. Do you want an example for that?

Comment: S.Pols yes are you talking about putting php on input ? echo checked = checked ? the js do works. but i wanted it on php.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use Jquery, you can just use javascript:

```
<td><input type="radio" onclick="q1 = true; func()" onselect="func()" name="Dquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
```

Just add the onclick function for each of your radio buttons

```
<body onload = "go()">
```

start function `go` when the body is loaded (this will set the submit button to disabled)

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var q1 = false;
var q2 = false;
var q3 = false;
var q4 = false;
var q5 = false;
    function go (){
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    }

function func() {
    if (q1 == true && q2 == true && q3 == true && q4 == true && q5 == true) {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
    };
}
</script>
```

Now add a variable for each of the questions, It checks if all the "q" variables are true, if they are submit will be enabled

=================================

## EDIT

You can use an array, you'll still need to say that every array is false, then your script should look like this:

```
var q = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
var tru = 0;
    function go (){
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    }

function func() {
    for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
        if (q[i] == true) {
            tru++;
            if (tru == q.length) {
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
            };
        };
    };
}
```

now you just have to put false in that array as many times as you have questions, and the radio button look like this

```
<td><input type="radio" onclick="q[0] = true; func()" name="Dquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>

onclick="q[0] = true; func()"
```

the index of `q` is the question number - 1, so the index of question 1 is 0 etc...

=================================

## EDIT

You can check if the radiobuttons are checked in php on `data.php` because your form directs to data.php and you post all values in the form

```
if ($_POST['Dquestion[1]'] == null){
   echo "<script language=javascript>  window.location='quiz.html';</script>";
```

}
here you check if Dquestion[1] is empty, if it is it will redirect you to quiz.html.
not sure if the php is exactly right cuz i cant check it right now cuz im at work

Comment: cause i having 100 question for the quiz , if i using this way i need to have q1 - q100 , and i set all to true ?? should i use loop ?

Comment: do it come with php ?

Comment: You can use the POST method, but then you'll be redirected to another page and then redirected back so thats a bit useless. but to check it you can check it by doing: if ($_POST['test'] != null)
where test is the name of a checkbox, here you check if test has a value, but youll have to do it for each seperate question again

Comment: sorry i am not sure what you mean , can you give a sample or it ? thank you ~