# how i going to make all my radio checked and Validation with loop?

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="data.php" method="post">
<table id="strength_table" border="1" width="980">
            <tr>
                <td><p> 1. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am cool</label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 11 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 2. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am awsome </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 12 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 3. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am worry </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 13 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 4. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am fear </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 14 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 5. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am happy </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 15 -->
</form>
```

my intention is to make all my question being confirm and validation , i know how to do a few radio with validation , but how about in loop ? cause i got 100 question is hard to do one by one like this.

Comment: try `children().each()` from jquery library

Comment: Please delete your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27355205/1852589

Comment: Got it sorry about it.

Comment: Also, do you really need to show us ALL your radio buttons? A small sample would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with javascript and php validation. The javascript submits the form event and shows an alert if not all questions are answered. If all questions are answered it adds an input field to the form with all questions. You can use this input field in PHP to create a PHP check in your `data.php`. If you use the example below don't forget to add the id `answerForm` to your form.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).on('submit', '#answerForm',function(e)
    {       
        var data                = $(this).serializeArray();
        var questions           = new Array();
        var questionsCounter    = 0;

        $.each($('input[type="radio"]'), function()
        {
            if(questions.indexOf($(this).attr('name')) == -1)
            {
                questions.push($(this).attr('name'));
                questionsCounter++;
            }           
        });

        if(questionsCounter != data.length)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You did not answer all questions");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="allQuestions" value="'+questions.join(",")+'"/>')
        }       

    });

</script>
```

In your `data.php` you can use something like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).on('submit', '#answerForm',function(e)
    {       
        var data                = $(this).serializeArray();
        var questions           = new Array();
        var questionsCounter    = 0;

        $.each($('input[type="radio"]'), function()
        {
            if(questions.indexOf($(this).attr('name')) == -1)
            {
                questions.push($(this).attr('name'));
                questionsCounter++;
            }           
        });

        if(questionsCounter != data.length)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You did not answer all questions");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).prepend('<input type="hidden" name="allQuestions" value="'+questions.join(",")+'"/>')
        }       

    });

</script>
```

Note this is still 100% secure because the client-side termines which inputs are "required". If you want to do this server-side you should save the name attributes of your generated questions in your SESSION. Then you can compare the SESSION name-inputs with the submitted inputs.

**EDIT**

If you create your form manually you can add the name fields manually to the session. You will get something like this:

```
<form action="data.php" method="post">
<table id="strength_table" border="1" width="980">
    <tr>
        <td><p> 1. </p></td>
        <td><label> I am cool</label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        <?php $_SESSION['allQuestions']['Dquestion[1]']; ?>
    </tr><!-- 11 -->
    <tr>
        <td><p> 2. </p></td>
        <td><label> I am awsome </label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        <?php $_SESSION['allQuestions']['Iquestion[1]']; ?>
    </tr><!-- 12 -->
    <tr>
        <td><p> 3. </p></td>
        <td><label> I am worry </label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        <?php $_SESSION['allQuestions']['Hquestion[1]']; ?>
    </tr><!-- 13 -->
    <tr>
        <td><p> 4. </p></td>
        <td><label> I am fear </label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        <?php $_SESSION['allQuestions']['Aquestion[1]']; ?>
    </tr><!-- 14 -->
    <tr>
        <td><p> 5. </p></td>
        <td><label> I am happy </label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="1"> 1 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="2"> 2 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="3"> 3 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="4"> 4 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="5"> 5 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="6"> 6 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="7"> 7 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="8"> 8 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="9"> 9 </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        <?php $_SESSION['allQuestions']['Aquestion[1]']; ?>
    </tr><!-- 15 -->
</form>
```

You can use the same PHP code of my example above. Also be sure the  rule `session_start()` is on the top of every page, else your session won't work.

Comment: do both need to use jquery ? could it be pure php ? or this is the easyies way to do so ?

Comment: Euhm can you show the code which generates the input fields?

Comment: do you mean all input ? actually i type all input.

Comment: Yes that's what i ment. Then i think this is the fastest solution. You can also write manually all input fields to the session, but that's a lot of work to.

Comment: can you somehow show me one of the sample ? i think i will do it one by one if i cant fix it. thank you

Comment: thank you i will give it a try , appreciate your help friend.

Comment: how i going to add the $session to the php above ??

Comment: just add `<?php session_start() ?>` as the first line in each PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with

> my intention is to make all my question being confirm and validation

but if you just need to make a loop out of your code, you could do it like that:

```
<form action="data.php" method="post">
<table id="strength_table" border="1" width="980">
            <tr>
                <td><p> 1. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am cool</label></td>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?><td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[1]" value="1"> <?=$i?> </td><?php } ?>
            </tr><!-- 11 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 2. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am awesome </label></td>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?><td><input type="radio" name="Iquestion[1]" value="1"> <?=$i?> </td><?php } ?>
            </tr><!-- 12 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 3. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am worry </label></td>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?><td><input type="radio" name="Hquestion[1]" value="1"> <?=$i?> </td><?php } ?>
            </tr><!-- 13 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 4. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am fear </label></td>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?><td><input type="radio" name="Aquestion[1]" value="1"> <?=$i?> </td><?php } ?>
            </tr><!-- 14 -->
            <tr>
                <td><p> 5. </p></td>
                <td><label> I am happy </label></td>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?><td><input type="radio" name="Dquestion[2]" value="1"> <?=$i?> </td><?php } ?>
            </tr><!-- 15 -->
</form>
```

Or you could do a double loop and be even more curt:

```
<form action="data.php" method="post">
<table id="strength_table" border="1" width="980">
            <?php 
            $arr1 = array("Dquestion[1]", "Iquestion[1]", "Hquestion[1]", "Aquestion[1]", "Dquestion[2]");
            $arr2 = array("I am cool", "I am awesome", "I am worry", "I am fear", "I am happy");
            for($j=0; $j<5; $j++) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><p> <?=$j?>. </p></td>
                <td><label> <?=$arr2[$j]?></label></td>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) { ?><td><input type="radio" name="<?=$arr1[$j]?>" value="1"> <?=$i?> </td><?php } ?>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
</form>
```

P.S. I took the liberty of correcting "awsome" in "awesome". Sorry, it's a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: Wao thank is good skill i need that that , but what i means is i wanted the user to have all question filled , i dont wanted them to pass up empty question, how i am i going to do that ?